# representation of double and radix point

Tags: c++, double

According to what I know on double (IEEE standard) there is one bit for signus, 54 bits for mantissa, a base and some bits for exponent

the formula to get the double is : `(−1)^s × c × b^q`

Maybe I made some mistake but the idea is here.

I'm just wondering how we can know where to put the radix point with this formula.
If i take number, I get for instance:

```
m = 3
q = 4
s = 2
b = 2
(-1)^2 * 4 * 2^3 = 32
```

but I don't know where to put some radix point..

What is wrong here ?

EDIT:

Maybe q is always negative ?

Comment: The sign is on one bit only - how can s == 2? it's 0 for positive, 1 for negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

32 = 1 * 2^5, so mantissa=1, exponent=5, sign=0. We need to add 1023 to exponent when coding the exponent, so below we have 1023+5=1028. Also we need to remove digit 1 when coding mantissa, so that 1.(whatever) becomes (whatever)

Hexadecimal representation of 32 as 64-bit double is 4040000000000000, or binary:

```
0100 0000 0100 0000 0000 ... and zeros all the way down
               ^======== start of mantissa (coded 0, interpreted 1.0)
 ^===========^---------- exponent (coded 1028, interpreted 5)
^----------------------- sign (0)
```

To verify the result visit this [page](http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/IEEE-754/Decimal.html), enter 32 in first field, and click either Rounded or Not Rounded button (doesn't matter which one).

Answer (score 2):

I guess a look at the Wikipedia would've helped.

Thing is, that there is a "hidden" '1.' in the IEEE formula.

Every IEEE 754 number has to be normlized, this means that the encoded number is in the format:

```
(-1)^(sign) * '1.' (mantissa) * 2^(exponent)
```

Therefore, you have encoded 1.32, not 32.